# Random String Generator keeps adding to previous iterations

Tags: java

I am writing a program that takes a user's input for a string that must be of length 6, and creates a random version of that string. Then, it prints out 5-10 iterations of a randomised string. For example:

The input of 8 and abcdef would create 8 lines of random variations of abcdef. The program below does that, but it's adding strings together, as so:

abbdfe
abbdfeacbfed
and so on. Does anyone know how to change it so it would print abbdfe acbfed and so on.

I know there are some functional issues with my code but it works as a start.

```
package matrixMaker;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class matrixMaker 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 5 and 10, inclusively: ");
    int userInput = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter a string of length 6 characters: ");
    String textToChange = in.nextLine();
    String randomText = "";
    int length = 6;



    // Print error if text is not 6 characters long.
    while(textToChange.length() != 6) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error! Enter a string of length 6.");
    }

    // If input is 6 characters, print out randomText X amount of times, depending on the user's specification of user.
    if(textToChange.length() == 6)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= userInput; i++)
        {
            // Initialise array to create random order of chars.
            Random rand = new Random();
            char[] text = new char[length];

            for(int a = 0; a < length; a++)
            {
                text[a] = textToChange.charAt(rand.nextInt(textToChange.length()));
            }

            // Take the chars from array and concatenate them into a string of the same size as the text variable.
            for(int a = 0; a < text.length; a++)
            {
                randomText += text[a];
            }
            System.out.printf(randomText + "\n");
        }
    }

    in.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: variation ? did yo mind permtation or just a sequence of char composed by inpt chars?

Comment: move row no 15 `String randomText = "";` to row no 31 and check.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be initializing the variable randomText at the top of the method, but keep adding to the same variable inside the loop, so it will keep adding to itself.

```
String randomText = "";

randomText += text[a];
```

Either initialize the randomText String inside the loop, or after your last line inside the loop, assign it back to an empty string again.

Btw, you seem to have another error here:

```
// Print error if text is not 6 characters long.
    while(textToChange.length() != 6) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error! Enter a string of length 6.");
    }
```

This loop will go for infinite, you need to add a way to allow the user to change the input after the error is displayed.

```
while(textToChange.length() != 6)
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Enter a string of length 6.");
            in.nextLine();
            textToChange = in.nextLine();
        }
```

--Edit added to OP comment:
To print the character of the odd generated text on the odd row number; one way to do it is to consider pushing your generated randomText to an empty ArrayList which you initialize outside the loop..then you can loop over your ArrayList separately. You can think of ways to refactor this and put in an outside method in the way you like. like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 5 and 10, inclusively: ");
    int userInput = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter a string of length 6 characters: ");
    String textToChange = in.nextLine();

    int length = 6;

    // Print error if text is not 6 characters long.
    while (textToChange.length() != 6) {
        System.out.println("Error! Enter a string of length 6.");
        in.nextLine();
        textToChange = in.nextLine();
    }

    //new array list for results of random text generated
    ArrayList<String> randomTextArray = new ArrayList<>();

    // If input is 6 characters, print out randomText X amount of times, depending on the user's specification of user.
    if (textToChange.length() == 6) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= userInput; i++) {
            String randomText = "";
            // Initialise array to create random order of chars.
            Random rand = new Random();
            char[] text = new char[length];

            for (int a = 0; a < length; a++) {
                text[a] = textToChange.charAt(rand.nextInt(textToChange.length()));
            }

            // Take the chars from array and concatenate them into a string of the same size as the text variable.
            for (int a = 0; a < text.length; a++) {
                randomText += text[a];
            }
            randomTextArray.add(randomText);
            System.out.printf(randomText + "\n");
        }


        System.out.printf("Odd Characters \n");

        String oddCharsOfRandomText = "";
        for (int i=0; i < randomTextArray.size(); i++) {
            if (!(i%2 == 0)) { //resolve true only if we are in an odd line
                for (int x=0; x <= randomTextArray.get(i).length(); x++ ){
                    if (!(x%2 == 0)) { //resolve true only if we are in an odd character
                        oddCharsOfRandomText += randomTextArray.get(i).charAt(x);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.printf(oddCharsOfRandomText + "\n");
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did that and it worked out. Although that said, there is another part where I need to print out the odd characters of the odd rows of each line. For example:

afbced
abcfed
bcadef

From the above, that would print fcdcdf. I think I have a method for doing it, but any advice would be greatly appreciated. Will post my code here later.

Comment: @LukeByrne I've edited my answer to give you a pointer on how to achieve your second part.

Comment: Thank you! I think that I have it right, I'm just fixing my formatting and putting in comments etc. Thank you for your help so far!